# htaccess - alias a old path to a new path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, path, alias

I'm not familiar with servers and htaccess commands. I think I have a simple question.

I put a index.php file on the root of localhost. That file will generate the following the following pages on this links:

- http://www.website.com/index.php?page=home
- http://www.website.com/index.php?page=services
- http://www.website.com/index.php?page=contact

---

**Old path adress:** http://www.website.com/index.php?page=home
**New path adress:** http://www.website.com/home

When user access the new path adress, I want the server to show what old path contains.
I want to use alias, no redirect. 
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the links in your content all look like: `http://www.website.com/home` then add these rules to your htaccess file in your document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```